# Cannot unbind mousemove with pageX and pageY

Tags: jquery, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup

```
var mouseStillDown = false;
$(".grab").mousedown(function(e) {
        mouseStillDown=true;
        getLocation();
    }).mouseup(function(e) {
        mouseStillDown = false;
        getLocation();
    });

if(mouseStillDown) {
$("#image_360").bind("mousemove", function(e){
     $("#location").text("e.pageX: " + e.pageX + ", e.pageY: " + e.pageY);
});
}

else if(!mouseStillDown) {
    $("#image_360").unbind("mousemove", function(e){
     $("#location").text("removed location");
    });
}
```

Even though I have unbound mousemove, I still get text with pageX and pageY showing up on my div with `id=location`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `$("#image_360").unbind("mousemove");`

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/